# symfony custom locale prefix configuration

Tags: php, symfony, locale

I'm looking for a way to customize the locale prefixes configuration for different clients.

I have defined this as shown in the Symfony documentation

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '' # don't prefix URLs for English, the default locale
        nl: '/nl'
```

Is it possible to override these settings in a custom config file ? for example if a site would need fr as the default locale, what would be the best way to go ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you must change in services.yaml

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    # This parameter defines the codes of the locales (languages) enabled in the application
    app_locales: en|fr|de
```

and in annotations.yaml

```
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
      _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
       _locale: '%locale%'
```

see more in : [symfony demo](https://github.com/symfony/demo)
[This component provides access to the localization](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/intl.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately after trying, it doesn't reproduce the same behavior as the config in my question. The important requirement is to have an empty prefix for the default locale. In your example conf, the route https://thedomain.com will return a 404. I have quite a few approaches such as importing the config in services.yml or kernel.php but so far no success, the question remains open